# Changing a root file system from initramfs to JFFS2

Tags: boot, initramfs, root-filesystem

I am running Linux on an ARM based development board from flash memory.  The rootfs is *initramfs*. I chose this in the configuration utility under *"file system"*.

Then I realized that I need persistent memory and *initramfs* is in RAM. So I want to switch to JFFS2. Then I selected Jffs2 in configuration menu and I got image.ub (as always) and this time a new file called rootfs.jffs2.

Now  I have to put three things in the flash;

```
1- bootloadeer (uboot) in mtd0
2- image.ub in mtd1
3- rootfs.jffs2 in mtd3
```

I did this by the command `flashcp -v rootfs.jffs2 /dev/mtd3`

But my kernel is hanging at "starting kernel..."
This was also happening when I was keeping mt3 (where I am a supposed to put rootfs.jffs2) empty.

It means that kernel is not getting file system. Can someone tell me if the procedure for putting rootfs.jffs2 described above is correct. Means is it sufficient just to use the flashcp command above and put jffs2 file or there is any other thing also that I have to perform?